# Let $C$ be the ellipse $x^2/4 + y^2/9 = 1$ traversed once in the positive direction, $G''(−i)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

My answer is different from the one chegg.

Let C be the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{9} = 1$ traversed once in the positive direction, and define

$$
G(z) :=\int_C \frac{\zeta^2-\zeta+2}{\zeta-z}\, d\zeta \hspace{8mm}  \text{(z inside ${c}$)}
$$
Find $G''(-i)$.

The following is  my answer.
$$
G''(-i) = \int_C \frac{\zeta^2-\zeta+2}{(\zeta + i)^3})\, d\zeta 
$$

$$
\begin{align}
f(\zeta) &= \zeta^2-\zeta+2\\
f'(\zeta) &= 2\zeta-1\\
f''(\zeta) &= 2
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
G''(-i) &= \frac{2 \pi}{2!} \cdot f''(-i) \\
&= \pi i \cdot 2 \\
&= 2 \pi i
\end{align}
$$

However, the correct answer from Chegg is $4\pi i$. where did I get wrong?

Comment: Where did you get the formula for $G”(-i)$?

Comment: @TedShifrin
Cauchy’s Integral Formula

Comment: Check your constants? When you’re off by a simple numerical factor, this should be the first thing you yourself think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(z)=2z^2-z+1$, $f''(z)=4$ rather than $2$.

However, that's not where the problem lies. You should have got that$$G''(z)=2\oint_C\frac{\zeta^2-\zeta+2}{(\zeta-z)^2}\,\mathrm d\zeta.$$

On the other hand, note that$$G(z)=2\pi i(z^2-z+2),$$by Cauchy's integral formula. It's easier to solve the problem using this.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my dumb mistake. Are there any other problems in my procedure?

Comment: The concerned variable is not $z$ but $\zeta$.

Comment: @JeanMarie I have changed my variable to $\zeta$. Plz have a look at my answer. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I have expanded my answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos
$G''(z)=2\oint_C\frac{\zeta^2-\zeta+2}{\zeta-z}\,\mathrm d\zeta$

How did you get 2 as the coefficient? Could you explain a little bit?

Comment: My mistake. It should be$$G''(z)=2\oint_C\frac{\zeta^2-\zeta+2}{(\zeta-z)^2}\,\mathrm d\zeta.$$It comes from the fact that, if you differentiate $\frac1{(\zeta-z)^2}$ with respect to $z$, what you get is $\frac2{(\zeta-z)^3}$.

Comment: I haven't been clear in my previous remark : I still don't agree. The differentiation is alike a differentiation under the integral symbol, therefore doing it twide, one must have a denominator $(z-\zeta)^3$

Comment: @JeanMarie Could you write your full answer as an answer? The comment section don't give you enough space to express your idea clearly

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  if you differentiate $1/(ζ−z)^2$ with respect to z, what you get is $-2/(ζ−z)^3$. You forget the negative sign.

Comment: Sloppiness everywhere. There was a typo in José’s answer. But there are no negative signs because of the $-z$ and the chain rule. But you, kile, missed the factor when you differentiated at the outset. That was the point of my original comment.

Comment: @kile Since $\frac1{(\zeta-z)^2}=(\zeta-z)^{-2}$, it follows from the chain rule that, if we differentiate $\frac1{(\zeta-z)^2}$, what we get is$$2(\zeta-z)^{-3}=\frac2{(\zeta-z)^3}.$$